# Linear operators exercise

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

How do i prove that if $T$ is a linear operator of $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $\left\Vert T-I \right\Vert<1 $, then $T$ is invertible and $\mathop{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(I-T\right)^{k}}$  absolutely converges to $T^{-1}$ ? In my notes there are the properties of linear operators but I don't know how to use them in this exercise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know geometric sums and geometric series? Set $A=I-T$, or $T=I-A$, then $TS_n=(I-A)\sum_{k=0}^nA^k=...$

Comment: how do i continue?

Comment: Just to check what I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (T-I)^k$. We know that $||(T-I)^k|| \leq ||T-I||^k$, so we can apply the Weierstrass $M$-test to show that $S_n$ converges absolutely.

Now use the summation formula for a geometric series.

Comment: why is invertible then?

Comment: and does the Weierstrass M-test give where it converges precisely?

Comment: It is invertible because $S_n$ converges to $T^-1$ which is therefore well-defined. It converges everywhere. You might be confusing this concept with convergence of real-valued series.

Comment: but does $I/T$ make sense?

Comment: Not like that, strictly - you can show that it is the operator you're looking for by proving that $TS_n$ and $S_nT$ converge to $I$, so $\lim S_n$ must be $T^{-1}$.